Question relating isomorphisms and structures in logic
A question in a sheet was as follows:

Let $T_n,$ $n \in\mathbb N \setminus 0,$ be the structure $⟨N; f_n)$
where $f_n(a) = \lfloor\frac{a}{n}\rfloor.$ Draw a picture of Tn for n = 1, 2, 3.

For T1 I drew a number-line from 1 to infinity
For T2 I drew a number-line of 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, ...
For T3 I drew a number-line of 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, ...
In the feedback all that was written was that "these structures are not isomorphic". I am confused why this is relevant as isomorphism doesn't seem relevant to the question to me; I think I must be lacking some understanding of the question as this is the only way I can picture these structures. I can see that they aren't isomorphic to each other, but as I say I am unsure why that is relevant. The lecturer has not responded to my emails hence why I am inquiring here.

Please use MathJax instead of Unicode whenever you type a formula on this site.

What do you mean, "structure?" That is a vague term in mathematics. Can you give a context beyond "logic?" Logic usually doesn't involve much in the way of pictures, except for diagrams.

@ThomasAndrews "Structure" is actually a technical term in mathematical logic, see here.

The question is rather vague (what is a "picture" of a structure?). I think your lecturer may be expecting to sketch the graphs of the functions $f_n$ rather than enumerating $f_n(1), f_n(2), \ldots$ It is true that no two of the structures $T_n$ are isomorphic, but it seems to be irrelevant to the question as stated.

It seems that your convention is $0\in\Bbb N$, so you should insert one more $0$ ($f_n(0)=0$) at the beginning of each of your lists. Maybe this is why your lecturer said your structures are not isomorphic (not meaning "not isomorphic to eachother" but "not isomorphic to the ones (s)he described").

I would draw pictures of (initial segments) of these structures like this:
$T_1$: 
$T_2$:

$T_3$: 
